# Invalid view holder adapter while trying to call notifydatasetchanged() in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My Recyclerview was working fine , what i did was simple, i fetched data from a webervice and displayed it using recyclerView

This is my code for loading more data

```
public void loadmoredata(int limit) {
    limit++;
    String url = "http://oilpeople.talenetic.com/api/SearchJob?limit="+limit+ "&jobkeyword=" + key + "&countrytext=" + coun + "&location=" +loc+ "&apikey=1111111111&siteid=1";
    JsonObjectRequest loadmore = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray(loadArray);
                jobTitle = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                salary = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                companyName = new String[jsonArray.length()];

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    if(loadArray.equals("Indeedjobslist")) {
                        String salaryLoc = c.getString("location");

                        jobTitle[i] = c.getString("jobtitle");
                        companyName[i] = c.getString("companyname");
                        salary[i] = salaryLoc;
                    } else {
                        String salaryLoc = c.getString("salary")+ " \u2022 " +c.getString("location");

                        jobTitle[i] = c.getString("jobtitle");
                        companyName[i] = c.getString("companyname");
                        salary[i] = salaryLoc;
                    }

                    // show the values in our logcat

                    m.setCompanyName(companyName);
                    m.setJobTitle(jobTitle);
                    m.setSalary(salary);

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } catch(JSONException e) {

            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    Volley.newRequestQueue(SearchResults.this).add(loadmore);
}
```

adapter is a global variable. I am trying to load more data like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.fTextView.setText(jobTitle[position]);
    holder.mTextView.setText(companyName[position]);
    holder.sTextView.setText(jobs[position]);

    if (position % 10 == 0) {
        int limit = position + 5;
        loadmoredata(limit);
    }
}
```

Whenever the  % of position is 0 I load more data, but I am getting indexoutofBounds error.

Comment: add your logcat also

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
if (position % 10 == 0) {
    int limit = position + 5;
    loadmoredata(limit);
}
```

and use this method calling to know count from your main activity then call your above cod but i think that will cause infinite loop

```
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length;
}
```